# Export a class in Node module.exports = {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to export a class with static methods in a module, along with other functions. I'm trying to do

```
module.exports = {
  fun: function(){},
  class: MyClass
}
class MyClass {
  static get prop() {
    return 'property';
  }
}
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to export class as part of module.exports object?

Comment: I'm using not `class` but say `abc` and it's not working -- the error is that `abc` is not defined when I try to require it from other file. 
I can do module.exports.abc = MyClass, but that would not allow me to use just `MyClass` inside the module

Comment: I see `myClass` and not `MyClass` in your exports definition

Comment: Why don't you use ES6 module exports? `export class MyClass {} export function fun() {}`

Comment: @Bergi: ES6 module imports can only be on the top of the file. Sometimes it's necessary to conditional import a module. This is not possible then.

Comment: @andreas It will be possible with `import()` statements, and until then you can still just `require` the transpiled module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class definitions aren't hoisted, which means that your class won't be in scope when you declare those exports. Move them down to below the definition.

```
class MyClass {
  static get prop() {
    return 'property';
  }
}
module.exports = {
  fun: function(){},
  class: myClass
}
```

You'll also need to fix the case on the variable you export.

```
module.exports = {
  fun: function(){},
  class: MyClass
}
```

Depending on your Javascript environment, there may be compile time errors  if you try and used the reserved word `class` as a literal object property. You can wrap it in a string to avoid this.

```
module.exports = {
  fun: function(){},
  "class": MyClass
}
```

Comment: great, the problem was with hoisting, otherwise it was just an example code for stackoverflow. thank you sir